# Virtualenvwrapper creating python 3.2 envs?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

Whenever I create a new virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper, it installs python 3.2; how to I set it so that is sets up envs using python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following file exists and what it its content:

> ~/.virtualenv/virtualenv.ini

There you can indicate the python interpreter you want for your virtualenvs by default, create it if necessary.

```
[virtualenv] 
python = /usr/bin/[python_version]
```

Comment: Then create the file, and add the settings there as showed in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing my .bashrc file.

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/VEnvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```